# Partially filled MPI Cartesian Grid

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, openmpi, topology

Is it possible to create an MPI Cartesian Grid which is only "partially" filled with nodes?
The following piece of code summarizes the issue. I'm creating a 4x4 grid and I ran the program with only 15 processors, which raises "MPI_ERR_DIMS: invalid topology dimension" error.

Below is the code which reproduces the error (when ran with a number of processors less than 4x4=16):

```
MPI_Comm
create_topology(int size)
{
    MPI_Comm grid;
    int dims[2] = {4,4};
    int periods[2] = {0,0};

    MPI_Dims_create(size, 2, dims);
    printf("dims = {%d,%d}", dims[0], dims[1]);
    MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 2, dims,
        periods, 0, &grid);

    return grid;
}

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MPI_Comm topo;
    int rank, size;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    /* Initializing the grid */
    topo = create_topology(size);

    /* Printing coordinates */
    int coords[2];
    MPI_Cart_coords(topo, rank, 2, coords);

    if(rank == 0) {
        printf("Root:    [%d] -> [%d,%d]\n",
            rank, coords[0], coords[1]);
    } else {
        printf("Process: [%d] -> [%d,%d]\n",
            rank, coords[0], coords[1]);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried to directly pass a dims[]{4,4} array, without using the MPI_Dims_create function, which raised an MPI_ERR_ARG from MPI_Cart_create.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I suppose you might be able to oversubscribe, run 2 processes on one processor and slow down your entire computation as if you had only 8 processors available.  But as you might guess, I can't see the point of that.  Or you could remap your problem to `3x5` when you can't map it to `4x4`.  But beyond those fancies, what would you like to do with the 16th fraction of your computation ?

Comment: This is only for practical purposes, as I do not want my program to crash or misbehave if the user supplies a number of processors that is not a power of two.

Comment: In summary, I would like my virtual topology to always be a square grid no matter what

Comment: I amend my previous message: I meant "that is not a square number", instead of "that is not a power of two"

Comment: Well, the largest square number no greater than 15 is, of course, 9, so you would set up a 3x3 grid if a scoundrel only offered your program 15 processors to run on.  But you're robbing yourself of the fun of programming a decomposition across however many processors your program finds itself on at run time.  And in case it's not clear from my earlier comment - it's certainly possible to create a cartesian grid on only a fraction of the processes at run time, for that you might want to investigate `mpi_comm_split`.